# Displaying full names of tensorflow graph nodes

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a tensorflow graph for an operation. Everything works fine and the graph looks as expected but the graph nodes do not display full text. I would like to include this graph in a presentation and it is nice to have full names of the graph nodes. Image displayed below shows how the names on my nodes appear currently.

[image: Current tensorflow node]